# USPS API Address Validation Fail

Tags: php, xml, usps

I'm trying to use the USPS API to validate an address. I've gone through the registration process, testing, and promotion to production.

I'm using PHP and the simplexml_load_file function to make the call. When I make the call in PHP, USPS returns an error:

```
[Number] => 80040B1A
[Description] => API Authorization failure. Verify is not a valid API name for this protocol.
[Source] => USPSCOM::DoAuth
```

If I copy and paste the url passed to the simplexml_load_file function, I get a successful response:

```
<AddressValidateResponse><Address ID="0"><Address2>1228 E MAIN ST</Address2><City>MONTROSE</City><State>CO</State><Zip5>81401</Zip5><Zip4>5821</Zip4></Address></AddressValidateResponse>
```

The url I'm using is (user ID changed):

```
http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=Verify&XML=%3CAddressValidateRequest%20USERID=%123usrid456%27%3E%3CAddress%20ID=%270%27%3E%3CAddress1%3E1228%20East%20Main%20Street%3C/Address1%3E%3CAddress2%3E%3C/Address2%3E%3CCity%3EMontrose%3C/City%3E%3CState%3ECO%3C/State%3E%3CZip5%3E81401%3C/Zip5%3E%3CZip4%3E%3C/Zip4%3E%3C/Address%3E%3C/AddressValidateRequest%3E
```

I've called in to the 800 ICCC USPS number twice. The documentation is lacking in several respects, for instance, they say after registration the email will contain the url of the testing servers, but they aren't in the email. Also, having to call in for support and waiting on hold for almost an hour each time is frustrating. Ok, so enough complaining. Otherwise, USPS is awesome.

I've read numerous posts, and tried what was suggested, but haven't been able to make the call in PHP work. Here's what I've tried:

- urlencode the XML string in the url submitted
- urlencode the entire url
- test and production servers
- curl instead of simplexml_load_file
- I've copied the url that works from the browser address bar and pasted it into the PHP code - and I still get the same error.

I'm at a loss as what I should try next. Especially when I take the url passed to simplexml_load_file and copy/paste it into the browser address bar works properly.

Here's a snippet I've tried:

```
$url = "http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=Verify&XML=<AddressValidateRequest%20USERID='123usrid456'><Address ID='0'><Address1></Address1><Address2>1228 East Main Street</Address2><City>Montrose</City><State>CO</State><Zip5>81401</Zip5><Zip4></Zip4></Address></AddressValidateRequest>";
$addr_data = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

*User ID changed* in the code above

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks in advance!

Sloan

Answer (score 0):

Along with the HTTP GET request you not only send the address (which is presumably the same in your browser and simpleXML) but a bunch of headers too (e.g. cookies). I hazard a guess that the API also checks those headers. It is a bit odd for me that a user name is specified but access information (token/key/password) is not - aren't they sent by your browser as cookies? Take a new look at the API specification, especially general/authentication chapters; maybe you just forgot some prerequisite that is stashed away in those.

Here's what I'd do:

1. Transition temporarily to curl so I can change the headers.
2. Use the network debugger of a browser (e.g. Firefox F12->Net) to see what headers are sent.
3. Set up the exactly same headers in curl and see if it works. If it does not the discontinue with this approach.
4. Remove header one-by-one to see which are essential to success.

Comment: Thanks. I did as you suggested, but I don't get any results when using curl. I set the options as:
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TRANSFERTEXT, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

 $rslt = curl_exec($ch);
$rslt is empty...

Comment: Could you please post a copy of what Firefox debugger (F12) Net panel lists for Request headers? Maybe we can figure something from that. Another thing you could give a try is whether the URL also works if you put it into a private browsing window.